# What is the best service to use for data pipelines on GCP

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine

I wanna deploy service (python script that uses Apache Beam) on my project on GCP with execution time sometimes up to 24h. I need this service with the data pipeline to be always working. Also I have a web application that's gonna use the results from the data pipeline. My solution for this was that I deploy the web app on GCP App Engine and the python script on K8s cluster because the job can last up to 24h and App Engine is serverless so everything in serverless should be a short time job something like up to 15mins. Am I on the right way of thinking or you have some other better solution for GCP services to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache Beam my advice is that you deploy the pipeline on [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow). The service is fully managed by GCP, and in fact this product was the one open sourced in the [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org) project, so using the product should be straight forward.

Once processed the data by Dataflow, you can write your results to several possible destinations, like BigQuery, GCS, Pub/Sub, Datastore, and consume these results from your Web App. Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.html).

Please, only, pay attention on the required processing time: Dataflow will scale as needed but even in that case, if your jobs takes 24 hours to run, is certainly something you must test and study carefully, Also review the possible associated costs.